# CORS in Startup and Azure. Why both?

Tags: .net

Why CORS has to be configured in Startup.cs and Azure Portal to be available to all users?
Why both?

Regards,
Mafyou.

Comment: The Azure portal is rather large. Which section are you referring to? Azure App Service?

Comment: For a Web API. It has to be configured for both to work.